# How can I temporarily halt program execution using a bool in C# and resume it when the bool is true?

Tags: c#

How do you "pause" a program (like a breakpoint) while a bool (codepause) is false, then when codepause is true the program "resumes" (as if you pressed continue while debugging in VS)?

I haven't tried anything yet as I don't know what to do.

Comment: What is the scenario you're trying to implement? Please provide as much detail as you can.

Comment: Have a look at [`ManualResetEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualresetevent?view=net-7.0). And its siblings.

Comment: @Fildor How do you know that's an appropriate solution? This is pretty clearly a beginner question and a recommendation to look into thread synchronization and signaling methods is probably overkill.

Comment: @DanielMann that's why it's not an answer. Question is far too vague to suggest anything. And it's as close to "a bool" as you can get while still making some sense at all.

Comment: How would `codepause` be set to true? Your programm cannot do this because it is halted.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can use a boolean variable in combination with a loop to temporarily halt program execution until the boolean condition is true.

Here's an example:

```
 using System;
 class Program
{
static bool isPaused = true;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Press 'p' to pause and 'r' to resume.");
    Console.WriteLine("Enter 'q' to quit the program.");

    // Start a separate thread to monitor the pause/resume input
    // while the main thread continues executing.
    var inputThread = new System.Threading.Thread(ReadInput);
    inputThread.Start();

    // Main program loop
    while (true)
    {
        // Check if the program is paused
        while (isPaused)
        {
            // Wait for a short duration before checking again
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        // Resume program execution
        Console.WriteLine("Program resumed");
        
        // Perform your program logic here

        // Exit the program if 'q' is entered
        if (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar == 'q')
            break;
    }

    // Stop the input thread before exiting
    inputThread.Join();
}

static void ReadInput()
{
    while (true)
    {
        // Read user input
        var key = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

        // Pause the program if 'p' is entered
        if (key == 'p')
        {
            isPaused = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Program paused");
        }

        // Resume the program if 'r' is entered
        if (key == 'r')
        {
            isPaused = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Program resumed");
        }

        // Quit the program if 'q' is entered
        if (key == 'q')
            break;
    }
}
 }
```